# how to make several redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, hyperlink

Right now I am updating my web site and I want to change all links to non-extension links like `example.com/test.php` to `example.com/test`. THis solution I found I put in  .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(([^/?]*/)*[^/?]+)\.php

RewriteRule ^.+\.php$ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

But at the same time I need to make redirection for links what located in lower level of my web-site like `example.com/level/test2.php` to `example.com/test2.php`.
What should I write in .htaccess to redirect my files from lower level to higher and remove .php extension at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate your groupings and backreference the 2nd one, not the entire thing:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /([^/?]*/)*([^/?]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^.+\.php$ /%2 [L,R=301]
```

Essentially, `/(([^/?]*/)*[^/?]+)\.php` is changed to `([^/?]*/)*([^/?]+)`, then `%1` is changed to `%2` in the rule's target.